# How to use nexus as a tag

Tags: tags, nfc, nexus-s

I want to use nexus s as a tag and read it by nfc shield arduino. How to do it ?
I want to keep my id in tag and nfc shield will read id and record it.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The NFC Shield for Arduino is technically compatible with the Nexus S phone. You need to configure the Arduino as  peer-to-peer [initiator or target](http://seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield#uint32_t_PN532%3a%3aconfigurePeerAsInitiator.28uint8_t_baudrate.29) and implement a peer-to-peer protocol supported by Android: [NPP](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/ndef-push-protocol.pdf) or [SNEP](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/). Using the Android [NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage%28android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29) method, you can send then send data to the Arduino. The Arduino will also be able to send data to the phone.

Comment: do you have java code to run android phone and send id to the shield

Comment: i use p2pdemo from phonegap to send message to the board. How to set the board to receive message from the phone ?